# for loop iterating over a list of data frames

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop that first checks if it is a data frame. If it is a data frame then iterates over the data frames and calculates the mean and then creates a new column with the mean value. Here is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Number = c(45,62,27,34,37,55,40))
df2 <- data.frame(
  Number = c(15,20,32,21,17,18,13))
df3 <- data.frame(
  Number = c(12,32,22,14,16,21,30))

L <- list(df1,df2,df3)

for(i in L){if(is.data.frame(i)){
  i$Average <- mean(i)
}
}
```

and an example of the result I am after for df1 would be:

```
 Number  Average
1     45 42.85714
2     62 42.85714
3     27 42.85714
4     34 42.85714
5     37 42.85714
6     55 42.85714
7     40 42.85714
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` will only be a temporary object used to control your `for` loop.  To make changes to the dataframes stored in `L` outside of the loop try indexing by number like this.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Number = c(45,62,27,34,37,55,40))
df2 <- data.frame(Number = c(15,20,32,21,17,18,13))
df3 <- data.frame(Number = c(12,32,22,14,16,21,30))

L <- list(df1,df2,df3)

for(i in 1:length(L)){if(is.data.frame(L[[i]])){

## Requires explicitly extracting the values in 
## L[[i]] by name.  So could be problematic if you actually
## have many columns in your dataframes.  
L[[i]]$Average <- mean(L[[i]]$Number)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If we need to update the original data.frame objects with the new value, then use `assign`

```
nm1 <- paste0("df", 1:3)
for(i in seq_along(L)) {
    assign(nm1[i], `[<-`(L[[i]], "Average", value = mean(L[[i]]$Number)))
 }   

df1
#  Number  Average
#1     45 42.85714
#2     62 42.85714
#3     27 42.85714
#4     34 42.85714
#5     37 42.85714
#6     55 42.85714
#7     40 42.85714
```

---

Regarding why the OP's loop didn't work,

```
for(i in L) print(i)
```

returns the value of the `list` and not the names of the objects. So, we cannot an assignment `i$Average <-`.  The `list` elements don't have names.  Also, `mean` works on a `vector`.  It can be directly applied on `data.frame`

```
mean(L[[1]])
#[1] NA
```

> Warning message: In mean.default(L[[1]]) : argument is not numeric or
>   logical: returning NA

```
mean(L[[1]]$Number)
#[1] 42.85714
```

In the `for` loop, it means we get NAs

```
for(i in L) mean(i)
#  Warning messages:
#1: In mean.default(i) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
#2: In mean.default(i) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
#3: In mean.default(i) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Once, we extract the column 'Number', the `mean` works

```
for(i in L) print(mean(i$Number))
#[1] 42.85714
#[1] 19.42857
#[1] 21
```

---

But, it is easier to keep it in the `list` and update the datasets in the `list`.  Use `lapply` to create a column 'Average' by looping over the `list` and getting the `mean` of the 'Number'

```
lapply(L, transform, Average = mean(Number))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
L %>%
   map(~ .x %>%
            mutate(Average = mean(Number)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `purrr::map` to do this:

```
require(purrr)

L %>%
  map(
    .f =
      ~ .x %>%
      {
        if (is.data.frame(.)) {
          mutate(., Average = mean(Number))
        }
      }
  )

# [[1]]
#   Number  Average
# 1     45 42.85714
# 2     62 42.85714
# 3     27 42.85714
# 4     34 42.85714
# 5     37 42.85714
# 6     55 42.85714
# 7     40 42.85714
# 
# [[2]]
#   Number  Average
# 1     15 19.42857
# 2     20 19.42857
# 3     32 19.42857
# 4     21 19.42857
# 5     17 19.42857
# 6     18 19.42857
# 7     13 19.42857

# [[3]]
#   Number Average
# 1     12      21
# 2     32      21
# 3     22      21
# 4     14      21
# 5     16      21
# 6     21      21
# 7     30      21
```

Comment: Yep, it's just missing the `is.data.frame()` check.